# Verifying my understanding of eigenvector for a specific problem

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume we have $F = \begin{bmatrix}-c&s \\ s&c \end{bmatrix}$, and $J= \begin{bmatrix}c&s\\ -s&c \end{bmatrix}$ where $s=sin(\theta)$ and $c=cos(\theta)$ for some $\theta$. $det(F) = -1$ and it is a reflector (the special case of a Householder reflector in dimension $2$). $det(J) = 1$ and it performs the rotation.

In the part of discussion about  geometric effect of the left multiplication by $F$ and $J$ on plane $R^{2}$, it was written we can write $F = J\begin{bmatrix}-1&0 \\ 0&1 \end{bmatrix}$. So F reflects a vector on to $y$-axis then followed by a rotation. To find the type of reflection, we can find eigenvalue corresponding to $1$ which is $(s, c+1)^*$.

My Question:

I was trying to find the eigenvector of $F$ and $J$ but I couldn't get to this specific result.This what I tried:

$\begin{bmatrix} -c&s \\ s&c \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix}= \lambda \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix} s.t. \quad \lambda = 1$

$(-c-1)v_1+sv_2=0$

$sv_1+(c -1)v_2= 0$

I can see $\frac{v_1}{v_2}=\frac{s}{c+1}$ based on the first equation. Since $s^2+c^2=1$, the second equation is also true. How should we approach solving these linear equations to begin with?Is that correct to wrote $(s, c+1)^*$ as the eignevector for $\lambda=1$? or is this just one of the possibilities of eigenvector when eignevalue is equal to $1$?

Comment: @Moo Thanks for your comment. I did RREF and I got $v_1+\frac{s}{c+1}v_{2} = 0$. I did check what you wrote and found it held true. Based on the comments, It seems as long as a vector satisfies these equations it is acceptable as an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that there’s no such thing as *the* eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue. Any non-zero linear combination of eigenvectors for an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is also an eigenvector of $\lambda$.

In this case, the eigenvalues of $F$ are $1$ and $-1$, so the two eigenspaces are one-dimensionsal. Thus, once you find *any* eigenvector of $1$, any non-zero scalar multiple of it is also an eigenvector, and these are *all* of the eigenvectors of $1$. You’ve determined that they have the form $(v_2s/(c+1), v_2)$, so taking $v_2=c+1$ gives you the cited result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understood your answer except the part that you wrote one-dimensional eigenspace. I thought since it has two elements it is 2-D.

Comment: @Zereshki The overall space is two-dimensional, but each of the subspaces consisting of all of the eigenvectors of one of the eigenvalues of $F$ is only one-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have another question.May be I misunderstood something. Why is it wrong to say eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue? I saw it in some tutorials like this one[1].[1]https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/eigenstuff/eigenstuff.pdf

Comment: @Zereshki It’s sloppy terminology to use the definite article “the” as in “the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$” since there are an infinite number of them—if $v$ is an eigenvector, then any non-zero scalar multiple of it is, too. "An" is more correct. I point this out because many of the questions that I see here are the result of confusion on this point because of this use of “the.”